# Is there a way to dynamically build an atom name without a macro?

Tags: elixir

I would like to dynamically build a list of atoms that can have none or a different suffix, something like:

```
fields = [:title#{suffix}, :body#{suffix}]
```

Is there a sigil (or other simple approach)?
Or is a macro here simple enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by putting a `:` before a string, and the string can contain interpolations inside it:

```
iex(1)> suffix = "_foo"
"_foo"
iex(2)> fields = [:"title#{suffix}", :"body#{suffix}"]
[:title_foo, :body_foo]
```

Comment: Just to add a note to this, there is a max number of atoms allowed within the Erlang VM. This number defaults to 1,048,576. Dynamically creating atoms like this could crash the VM, or OOM your machine if you are acting on a small amount of memory.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there's a sigil for creating an atom

```
~w(foo)a => :foo
```

And you can use interpolation inside sigils to dynamically create atoms:

```
~w(title#{suffix} body#{suffix})a
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of approaches completeness, I would put it here: [`String.to_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1) would also work:

```
~w|title body|
|> Enum.map(& "#{&1}_foo")
|> Enum.map(&String.to_atom/1)
#⇒ [:title_foo, :body_foo]
```